# Need help to encrypt/decrypt files with this format => openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -in encryptedfilename -out plaintextfilename

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, openssl, aes

i have a website to encrypt and decrypt file and i want to create a flutter apps to encrypt and decrypt with the same format but i've got no clue how to do it, below is the format of the encryption

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -in encryptedfilename -out plaintextfilename
```

any suggestion on how do i create encrypt/decrypt function with format above? i've tried most of flutter encryption package but did not find any solution

```
   static Future<File?> aesEncryptTest(String password, File file) async {
    final _password = Password.hash(password, PBKDF2());
    var bytes = utf8.encode(_password);
    var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    var fDigest = md5.convert(digest.bytes);

    final key = Key.fromUtf8(fDigest.toString());
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));

    final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    final encryptedData = encrypter.encryptBytes(fileBytes, iv: iv);

    File _file =
        await File(file.path + '.enc').writeAsBytes(encryptedData.bytes);

    _file.writeAsBytesSync(encryptedData.bytes);

    await FileServices.saveFile(_file.path);

    
    return encryptedFile;
  }

  static Future<File?> aesDecryptTest(String password, File file) async {
    final _password = Password.hash(password, PBKDF2());
    var bytes = utf8.encode(_password);
    var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    var fDigest = md5.convert(digest.bytes);

    final key = Key.fromUtf8(fDigest.toString());
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));

    final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(Encrypted(fileBytes), iv: iv);

    File _file =
        await File(withoutExtension(file.path)).writeAsBytes(decryptedBytes);

    _file.writeAsBytesSync(decryptedBytes);

    await FileServices.saveFile(_file.path, extraName: 'DECRYPTED');

    return File(decryptedFile);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encryption, in the Dart code:

- a random 8 bytes salt must be generated,
- the 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV must be derived from the password and salt using PBKDF2,
- the plaintext must be encrypted with the derived key and IV using AES-256, CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding,
- the data mus be formatted in OpenSSL format: ASCII encoding of `Salted__` plus 8 bytes salt plus ciphertext.

A possible implementation is:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
import 'dart:io';

...

// generate random 8 bytes salt
SecureRandom secureRandom = getSecureRandom();
Uint8List salt = secureRandom.nextBytes(8);

// derive key and IV via password and salt
Uint8List passphrase = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode('my passphrase'));
Uint8List keyIv = deriveKeyIv(salt, passphrase);
Uint8List key = keyIv.sublist(0, 32);
Uint8List iv = keyIv.sublist(32);

// encrypt using AES-256, CBC mode
File ptFile = File('<path to plaintext.txt file>');
Uint8List ptFileBytes = await ptFile.readAsBytes();
Uint8List ciphertext = encryptAesCbcPkcs7(ptFileBytes, key, iv);

// apply OpenSSL format: Salted__ | <8 bytes salt> | ciphertext
Uint8List prefixSaltCiphertext = concatAndEncode(salt, ciphertext);

File ctFile = File('<path to ciphertext.enc file>');
await ctFile.writeAsBytes(prefixSaltCiphertext);
```

with

```dart
SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
  List<int> seed = List<int>.generate(32, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256));
  return FortunaRandom()..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seed)));
}

Uint8List deriveKeyIv(Uint8List salt, Uint8List passphrase){
  PBKDF2KeyDerivator derivator = PBKDF2KeyDerivator(HMac(SHA256Digest(), 64))
    ..init(Pbkdf2Parameters(salt, 10000, 32 + 16));
  return derivator.process(passphrase);
}

Uint8List encryptAesCbcPkcs7(Uint8List plaintext, Uint8List key, Uint8List iv){
  PaddedBlockCipherImpl paddingCipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(PKCS7Padding(), CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine()))
    ..init(true, PaddedBlockCipherParameters(ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv), null));
  return paddingCipher.process(plaintext);
}

Uint8List concatAndEncode(Uint8List salt, Uint8List ciphertext){
  BytesBuilder prefixSaltCiphertext = BytesBuilder()
    ..add(utf8.encode('Salted__'))
    ..add(salt)
    ..add(ciphertext);
  return prefixSaltCiphertext.toBytes();
}
```

The ciphertext generated in this way can be decrypted with the posted OpenSSL statement (which by the way is for decryption and not encryption).

Here it must be taken into account that OpenSSL used MD5 as default digest in earlier versions and SHA256 as of v1.1.0. The above code assumes SHA256. If you have an older OpenSSL version, you can set `-md sha256` in the OpenSSL statement. Alternatively the code has to be adapted to MD5.

---

For decryption, in the Dart code:

- the 8 bytes salt and the ciphertext must be extracted from the encrypted data which is encoded in OpenSSL format,
- the 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV must be derived from the password and salt using PBKDF2,
- the ciphertext must be decrypted with this key and IV using AES-256, CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding.

The implementation is analogous to encryption:

```dart
// extract salt and ciphertext
File ctFile = File('<path to ciphertext.enc file>');
Uint8List ctFileBytes = await ctFile.readAsBytes();
Uint8List salt = ctFileBytes.sublist(8, 16);
Uint8List ciphertext = ctFileBytes.sublist(16);

// derive key and IV via password and salt
Uint8List passphrase = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode('my passphrase'));
Uint8List keyIv = deriveKeyIv(salt, passphrase);
Uint8List key = keyIv.sublist(0, 32);
Uint8List iv = keyIv.sublist(32);

// decrypt using AES-256, CBC mode
Uint8List decryptedText = decryptAesCbcPkcs7(ciphertext, key, iv);
File dtFile = File('<path to decrypted.txt file>');
await dtFile.writeAsBytes(decryptedText);
```

with

```dart
Uint8List decryptAesCbcPkcs7(Uint8List ciphertext, Uint8List key, Uint8List iv){
  PaddedBlockCipherImpl paddingCipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(PKCS7Padding(), CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine()))
    ..init(false, PaddedBlockCipherParameters(ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv), null));
  return paddingCipher.process(ciphertext);
}
```